# How to save file object inside of the redux store

Tags: reactjs, file, redux, react-redux

I am building application with react.js that includes saving informations about building company workers. For each person one component will be created that includes input to fill informations about the worker with image. And the datas should be saved in redux store in array of workers. The problem is I cannot save the image file object in my redux store. But it should be saved, and all the information about workers should be sent with one reuest to backend server as an array.

I tried to save it like the following:

```
        <input
            type="file"
            id="imageFile"
            name="image"
            onChange={(e) => {
              dispatch(
                saveWorkerData({  // this is the function used just to add worker data to array of  workers in redux store
                  name: "John Doe",
                  age: 34, //etc
                  image: e.target.files[0],
                })
              );
            }}
         />
```

## But it gives: serializableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:234 A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `payload.image`

> How can I save the file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not advised to store non-JSON-serializable data in a Redux store you can choose to ignore this and store what you want/need. In this case you'll need to configure the serializability middleware to ignore certain actions and/or parts of state that may contain non-serializable values.

Example:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import { saveWorkerData } from '../slices/data';

const nonserializableActions = [saveWorkerData];

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [...nonserializableActions],
      },
    }),
});
```

See the [Serializability Middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/serializabilityMiddleware) documentation for more details.